# ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "<EOF>" in Java Derby

Tags: javadb

When I try to execute this line of code in Java

> String query = "create table keeplog(idk INT not null primary key
>   GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),"
>                     + "idl INT not null";           Statement stm = conn.createStatement();             stm.executeUpdate(query);

I received this error:

> ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "" at line 1, column 124.

When I used MySQL, I never met this error. Is the same code utilized in MySQL, but because I want to embed the application I switch to Java DB...
What can I do?

Comment: Don't exist anybody who can help me?

Comment: I solved my problem.. I forgot to put " ) " at the end of quotes. I am sorry..